# Error: You need JSON-C for ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: json, postgis

I checked the links with same error but did not find a solution to my error.

I am working with **postgreSQL 15** and **postGIS 3.2** which I installed from source.

Now I am getting this error : `You need JSON-C for ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`

JSON-C was **not** installed before installing postGIS.

Now my question is:

Is it necessary to uninstall postGIS completely then reinstall it with JSON-C? If so HOW CAN I UNINSTALL IT SAFELY and COMPLETELY ? (I am working on a **centOS 7** server)

Or my problem can be solved otherwise?